# How to make an image align with the baseline in a horizontal layout?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have the following `s:HorizontalLayout` that works great for all controls except the `Image` and `BitmapImage` controls. They do not align vertically. The rest of the controls are aligned along the baseline but the images are sitting way below the other controls. Is there a way I can set the baseline of the images and adjust their vertical position?

```
<s:Group>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="4" verticalAlign="baseline"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:CheckBox label="Test"/>
    <s:CheckBox label="Select"/>
    <s:BitmapImage source="{MyIcon}" height="18"/>
    <s:Image source="{MyIcon}" height="18"/>
    <s:Label id="topLocation" minWidth="65"/>
</s:Group>
```